# How to style and change the width of the google translate element

Tags: html, css

I'm using google translate `div` for translating web pages.

I want to change it's `width` and make it a bit nicer either through bootstrap `class` or through `css`.

I've checked this on different places but the `width` is not being targeted anywhere,and it's style is not being fit to other elements I have already on my site because other elements are using bootstrap and this one **do not**.

Here is my code;

```js
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({
      pageLanguage: 'en'
    },
    'google_translate_element');
}
```

```html
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
```

I've added the following script to my file.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit">
```